# How to avoid Assembly.LoadFrom blocking?

Tags: vb.net, assemblies, loading, file-locking

I create a .net dll on the fly with codedom then I load it with Assembly.LoadFrom like this:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim ASM As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("test.dll")
'Do some stuff with the loaded assembly...
End Sub
```

it works only once. If I try to recompile the test.dll i get the error that the file is used and not writable.
I tried to set ASM to nothing  - **how can I unload the loaded Assembly from the memory?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loaded assemblies can only be unloaded by destroying the AppDomain in which they are loaded.  Review the How To article links on this [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx).